# Using JOIN on several tables matching a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a dilemma, I would like to use JOIN on all of my 22 tables to combine them into one long row for each `company` I have a main table `company` that has a `CompanyID` as a primary key and 22 other tables that reference `company.CompanyID` some of the tables do not contain an entry of the company while others do. So if I use INNER JOIN the company that does not contain an entry in one of the tables does not show up. Is there a way to make it show up regardless?

```
SELECT * FROM `company` C
INNER JOIN sales S ON S.CompanyID = C.CompanyID
INNER JOIN owner O ON O.CompanyID = S.CompanyID
```

For example I have 5 companies in my database only 4 of them show up with the above statement because one of them does not contain an entry at all inside of `owner`.

Comment: This is MySQL syntax, so I'm removing the sql-server tag.

Comment: Use `left outer join` instead.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Oh wow that works great! Is there a way to remove the foreign key from the results so that it only displays once. I know I can do a selective SELECT 'This', 'That', 'etc' but I wonder if there is a cleaner way since there are almost 200 columns

Comment: @hjpotter92 if I don't use `SELECT *` then I have to type every column I want individually correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the duplicate ids, use the `using` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM `company` C LEFT OUTER JOIN
      sales S
      USING (CompanyID) LEFT OUTER JOIN
      owner O
      USING (CompanyID);
```

The `using` clause will output only one copy of each ID (in the more recent versions of MySQL -- this behavior has changed over time).

Answer (score 3):

When your Reference key table dost not have primary key record but still you need that record the use [LEFT JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html)

Try like this

```
SELECT * FROM `company` C
LEFT JOIN sales S ON S.CompanyID = C.CompanyID
LEFT JOIN owner O ON O.CompanyID = S.CompanyID
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually its quite easy, you should use LEFT JOIN to fetch all the records from the master table, remember LEFT JOIN will return all the records of the left table.

so the query will be something like this

```
SELECT * FROM `company` c
LEFT JOIN sales S ON c.CompanyID  = S.CompanyID 
LEFT JOIN owner O ON O.CompanyID = S.CompanyID
and so on..
```